# How to convert this('113678) into this (one 1 three 6 seven 8) on python

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion

I want to create a program that can convert 
a specific number into a word

I have already built this

```
l = ['', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine']
n =['0','1','2','3','4

def fun(str): 



word1 = l[int(str[0])]
word2 = l[int(str[2])]

num1 = n[int(str[1])]
num2 = n[int(str[3])]
s =   word1 + " "+ num1 + " " + word2 + " " +  num2
return s


print(fun("1136"))







output:One 1 Three 6
```

'''

but unfortunately that does not work as I want it to be

What I want

example :

input('1136')
output:one 1 three 6

input("113678")
one 1 three 6 seven 8

so it does not matter what the input is

I could have written word1 ... wordn 
                     num1 ... numn

But I think there should be a better way

I think I should write a for loop and 
if the index of int(str) is odd get element from (first list )
and when it is even get it from the other list

or maybe something like that

```
def fun(s): 

for i in range(len(s)):

    if (i %2 ==0):

        word1 = l[int(s[i])]


    elif(i %2 !=0):
        num1 = n[int(s[i])]

s =   word1 + " "+ num1
return s

  input: print(fun("113678"))
  output:seven 8
```

what about one 1 three 6

Thanks

Comment: If you got the answer, please accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dictionary: to get value faster
Yield = to avoid creating 2 extra lists and later on combining them

```
d= {0: 'Zero', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine'}

def get_word(value):
    l= 1
    while l <len(value)+1:
        rem = l % 2
        if not rem:
           yield d[int(value[l-1])]
        else:
            yield value[l-1]

        l +=1

for item in get_word('113678'):
    print(item, end=" ")
```

Explanation: get_word function is a generator and yield will return the value as soon as the value will be available and then proceed next.

OR

```
d= {0: 'Zero', 1: 'One', 2: 'Two', 3: 'Three', 4: 'Four', 5: 'Five', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Seven', 8: 'Eight', 9: 'Nine'}

def get_word(value):
    end = len(value)+1
    for even in range(1,end,2): # it will return [1,3,5]
        odd = even-1

        yield d[int(value[odd])]
        yield value[even]


for item in get_word('113678'):
    print(item, end="")
```